# Devise and confirmation emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Devise in my Rails app and am sending out emails for email confirmation, password reset, and password change advisory.

- I would like to know how I would pass in a different image into each of these emails so that I don't need to pass a load of HTML to the layout. Ideally, I would like to pass the image over to the layout if that is at all possible, maybe I need to do this in the controller?
- How would I go about sending out a different email if a user is only updating their existing email? Currently, devise sends the same confirmation email.
- Finally, how would I go about sending a welcome email once they have initially confirmed their account, and not if they are only updating their email?

All help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override devise mailer to meet your requirements.

First of all create `DeviseMailer`

```
# app/mailers/devise/mailer.eb
if defined?(ActionMailer)
  class Devise::Mailer < Devise.parent_mailer.constantize
    include Devise::Mailers::Helpers

    def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
      @token = token
      if record.pending_reconfirmation?
        devise_mail(record, :reconfirmation_instructions, opts)
      else
        devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
      end
    end

    def reset_password_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :reset_password_instructions, opts)
    end

    def unlock_instructions(record, token, opts = {})
      @token = token
      devise_mail(record, :unlock_instructions, opts)
    end
  end
end
```

Then just create needed views in `app/views/devise/mailer/` for each of methods:

- reconfirmation_instructions, will be called when user changes they email
- confirmation_instructions, will be called when user confirms they email
- unlock_instructions, when account is locked
- reset_instructions, on password reset

Actually you can create any template you'd like.

Hope that will help.

Comment: looks like what i need, awesome :D

Comment: how can i get it to pass in images so my layout can use the image that's passed int?

Comment: I've also noticed that the password changed email is no longer working? I tried to add in `password_change` but it's not working, any ideas?

Comment: Could you please explain where exactly you would like to pass an image?

Comment: It's ok i worked it out, i added a variable under the `@token` called `@emailimage`. This allowed me to send the required image into the email layout :D -- Still cant get the password updated email though

Comment: I'm not sure, but had you checked this advice? https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Notify-users-via-email-when-their-passwords-change ?

Comment: Actually it's not needed to create additional mailer, you can easily add `password_update` method to existing devise mailer.

Comment: I have tried `password_update` and `password_change` neither seem to be working. I will have another look into it shortly. Must be down to my naming of the methods.

Comment: Not `password_change` but `encrypted_password_changed?` that's an ActiveModel::Dirty http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html not devise